# json.parse fails on "unexpected token"

Tags: ruby

I am trying to parse a string that has Korean characters in it, and which is UTF-8 encoded. But `JSON.parse` fails on it, and I have no idea why. Any help?

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "{'a': '용국 . 지코 . 미노 . 지민 . 지용''}"
=> "{'a': '용국 . 지코 . 미노 . 지민 . 지용''}"
irb(main):002:0> s
=> "{'a': '용국 . 지코 . 미노 . 지민 . 지용''}"
irb(main):003:0> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):004:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> JSON.parse s
JSON::ParserError: 746: unexpected token at '{'a': '용국 . 지코 . 미노 . 지민 . 지용''}'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
from (irb):5
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON must be built using `"` (`'` isnt valid). Try any of the following:

```
s = "{\"a\": \"용국 . 지코 . 미노 . 지민 . 지용\"}"
s = '{"a": "용국 . 지코 . 미노 . 지민 . 지용"}'
```